# Python os.environ doesn't show empty environment variables

Tags: python, linux, shell, zsh

After an environment variable is exported and set to empty, I can't get its value in Python with `os.environ`. Is it expected?

Examples:

```
## export TEST_ENV_VAR
(base) ➜  Code export | grep TEST_ENV_VAR
TEST_ENV_VAR=''
(base) ➜  Code python
Python 3.8.12 (default, Oct 12 2021, 13:49:34) 
[GCC 7.5.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> 'TEST_ENV_VAR' in os.environ
False

## export TEST_ENV_VAR=''
(base) ➜  Code export | grep TEST_ENV_VAR
TEST_ENV_VAR=''
(base) ➜  Code python 
Python 3.8.12 (default, Oct 12 2021, 13:49:34) 
[GCC 7.5.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> 'TEST_ENV_VAR' in os.environ
True

## export TEST_ENV_VAR='TEST'
(base) ➜  Code export | grep TEST_ENV_VAR
TEST_ENV_VAR=TEST
(base) ➜  Code python                    
Python 3.8.12 (default, Oct 12 2021, 13:49:34) 
[GCC 7.5.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> 'TEST_ENV_VAR' in os.environ
True
```

The three samples above run in three different new terminals. I modified the .zshrc file to export different values. What's the difference between `export foo` and `export foo=''`?

Comment: I see no code difference in the first two cases

Comment: `export foo` has no effect if `foo` has not been defined previously.

Answer (score 2):

There is a difference between "Shell variables" and "Environment Variables" - see [here](https://superuser.com/questions/821094/what-is-the-difference-between-set-env-declare-and-export-when-setting-a-varia) - A shell variable is only available to the shell setting it whereas an environment variable is available to all child processes as well.

In `bash` - you can get the list of environment variables with `env`, and add to the environment variables with `export`

```bash
SHELL_VAR="10"
env | grep SHELL_VAR # No result
export ENV_VAR=100
env | grep ENV_VAR # ENV_VAR=100
```

Python shell (child process) picks the environment variables when you try an `os.environ`

```py
'SHELL_VAR' in os.environ # False
'ENV_VAR' in os.environ # True
```

Comment: Thank you! I thought a variable appearing in `export | grep foo` means it has been an environment variable but it seems not. So executing `export foo` only declares it as a shell variable but not an environment value, and the empty string is its default value?

Comment: See @norok2's answer and comment - `export foo` does nothing if foo has not been defined previously. If you want `foo` to hold an empty string - you need to set it explicitly - `export foo=''`

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the way you are defining your variables.

When you just do:

```bash
export FOO
```

no variable is actually exported unless `FOO` has been defined **previously**:

```bash
FOO=''
export FOO
```

or **concomitantly**:

```bash
export FOO=''
```

If `FOO` appears in `env | grep FOO`, it should appear in `os.environ`.

Comment: Thank you! `export FOO` seems to make `FOO` appear in `export`, so the command `export` shows all the shell variables but not the environment variables right?

Comment: @shb Nope. `export` will show the code used to declare the variables for the environment. Since `export FOO` result in an unser variable, the `declare` commands has no effect on the environment.

Comment: `export will show the code used to declare the variables for the environment.` That's what confused me. Thx!